# Why is it Important not to say you're planning to work with better opportunities?

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-search, career-development, colleagues

Sometimes when I get bored and I'm free. I usually browse jobs online seeking great opportunities. One day I received a reply from my "Dream Job". Out of my excitement, I have told it to my colleagues. One of my colleague said to me I shouldn't be saying this and this should be kept private. I felt guilt and curious about it.

Should I be keeping this private? Does this have a big impact with them?

Comment: It's not about guilt. It's just unwise to mention. Your colleague has been quite nice to you to give you that advice.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs can you elaborate what you meant by "unwise"

Comment: @Jon Are you planning to leave yet? It sounds far from certain. You would still have to interview with them, get an offer, etc. Wait until you're sure what you'll do.

Comment: @Brandin sure or not sure about the interview. I would like to know why is it unwise to mention any job offerings.

Comment: @Jon - because the guy you disclose this to now knows that you are a "flight risk" - you're looking to move away. He has to now consider informing management because it is something that impacts your company's ability to do what they do.

Comment: @Jon Your colleagues and your boss now know you may not stay long. They will be wary of giving you critical jobs, and at layoffs, if in doubt, you may be let go first, as you anyway may leave them at any time.

Comment: @Jon An interview is not a job offer. You're at step 0. When you get to step 4 or 5, you can start thinking about what you'll say, to whom you'll say it, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons this is a terrible idea. Off the top of my head, here are a few of the most obvious...

### It's bad for morale in multiple ways.

By looking for other, better jobs you're implying that you are **unhappy** in your current job, **and** that you think the things about your current job are so unlikely to change that the effort needed to make things work out is greater than the effort necessary to start over.

It also naturally raises questions with your other coworkers about whether you're leaving because you don't like them, or whether you think they're suckers for staying.

And it's demoralizing for the simple reason that you're going around telling people [how much better everywhere else is, which- regardless of all the other concerns- is in itself a depressing thing to constantly be telling people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_comparison_theory#Upward_and_downward_social_comparisons). By telling people about other good jobs, you may even be motivating other employees to leave as well.

Motivating employees is difficult and expensive. Replacing employees is difficult and expensive. As a result, a large part of your manager's job is to keep and motivate employees. By demotivating your teammates and motivating them to leave, you are costing the company money in both the short and long terms, and actively working directly in opposition to your manager's goals.

### It indicates to your manager that they need to replace you

Even if you're the only person on the team.

If you're looking for other jobs, and seem to be really excited about them, it's not unreasonable to assume that- one of these days- you're going to take one of those other jobs. The longer you stay on as an employee, the more valuable you become to the company, thanks to the on-the-job training you've received. Everything else being equal, if you've worked there for a year, and they suspect you'll leave within the next year, it makes no financial sense to keep you on for another year when they can replace you in a month with someone who's likely to stay for five or more years.

If you don't stay, the money invested in training you was a bad investment. They would be best suited forfeiting the sunk cost of training you and finding a replacement immediately.

Answer (score 14):

People talk. People overhear things. You mention to a colleague that you are considering other jobs, and a couple of hours later all of your managers will know it too. If you are an unusually valuable employee your managers *might* surprise you with a raise and a promotion in an attempt to keep you from leaving. More likely, they'll figure you are half-way out the door, and they'll begin treating you like the walking dead. Worst case, they'll decide that you are no longer reliable, and *push* you out the door before you actually have your new job lined up.

Comment: and the "dream job" could revealt itself to not be so worth.

Comment: This happened to me in my first job. I let wind I was looking to a colleague (albeit not that much), then later that very same day my manager was asking why I was looking for work elsewhere etc. It changed my working relationship instantly and it pushed me to look properly.